# Windows Service hosting MSMQ WCF service via ServiceHost is unable to write to Event Log or write files to system, but can move files around

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, windows-services, msmq

We have currently written a MSMQ WCF service hosted in a Windows Service that acts as an email  queuing service.  The idea is that all of our client applications, which can be accessed by multiple concurrent clients, can submit emails to one centralized reliable queuing system. Once an email is submitted, the service processes the job in the queue (which is a custom email object) and sends it off.

The issue we are encountering is that the portion of the code that actually opens the ServiceHost seems to be sandboxed and prevents our servicing code from writing to the event logs or writing to a custom log file (managed by NLog).  The oddity here is that the code also has functionality to move a file on the file system to another location - which works correctly - but as mentioned, cannot write to the event log nor the log file.  There is also no exception that appears to be thrown as we have the AppDomain.UnhandledException handler setup.

We have tried changing the Windows Service "run as" account several times from Local Service, to a Domain Admin, to a random user, but nothing seems to work. We are able to prove that before the actual "ServiceHost.Open()" call, we can successfully write to the event logs and the custom log file. It's only inside the actual class that is hosted by the ServiceHost that is having trouble.

I would like to think it's permissions, but as mentioned we can move files around - so it seems contradicting to say the least. The hosted environment is Windows Server 2003 R2 x64, and we are using .NET 4.0.

** As a note, if we remove the registry/custom logging code, and simply have the send email functionality (via a .NET SMTP client object), the emails send out correctly.

Snippet 1 - the WCF service code itself, simply trying to write to the registry, which does not work and apparently doesn't throw an exception:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class EmailQueueListener : IEmailQueuingService
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = false, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public void SendEmailToQueue(SerializableMailMessage emailMessage)
    {
        var eventLogSrc = "Email Service";
        var eventLogLogType = "[APP NAME HERE]";

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventLogSrc))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventLogSrc, eventLogLogType);

        EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSrc, "TESTING", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

Snippet 2 - the code initiating the service host, which is called from the OnStart method of the Windows service:

```
public static void Start(bool isConsole = false)
{
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        ConsoleLog.Info("TEST");

        var eventLogSrc = "Email Service";
        var eventLogLogType = "[APP NAME HERE]";

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventLogSrc))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventLogSrc, eventLogLogType);

        EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSrc, "Email Service Started", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        m_EmailServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(EmailQueueListener));
        m_EmailServiceHost.Open();
}
```